# Integrating Taylor's Approximation

Tags: calculus, statistics

I am reviewing Casella's All of Statistics. A particular integral comes up when reviewing non-parametric statistics in particular Histograms.

Assume that some $x\in B_j$ and any other $u \in B_j$ where $B_j$ is some particular bin in the histogram. I don't think the frequencies are going to  be too important here...

$$\int_{B_j}f(u)du \approx \int_{B_j}f(x) + (u-x)f^{\prime}(u)$$
$$= f(x)h + hf^{\prime}(x) ( h (j-\frac{1}{2})-x)$$

Now I can see that the first term is just base times height.... this is a histogram after all...

But that second term is bothering me. I can't think of a simple geometrical interpretation for what it means. I figure it is some sort of compensation for the value that exists between the histogram and the true $f$. Is this accurate? And if so where does a derivation of this exist? Or did I just forget my elementary calculus?

Comment: this video has all the necessary info: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3d6DsjIBzJ4

Comment: Oh nice! I love three blue one brown.